# Can I flip texture in cocos2d's particle system?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, flip, particles

I want to make an particle effect for fallen leaf or little paper fallen from above, like it was autumn or on a wedding. So I think maybe I could use a texture for leaf or paper, let them fallen from sky, in the mean time, texture should flip X/Y randomly. But I can't find any property or method to let me do this.

So my question is, can I?
If I can't flip texture anyway, how can I make the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CCParticleSystem itself can't flip the textures randomly.

But since CCParticleSystem derives from CCNode you could try and set the scaleX/scaleY property to -1 to flip the entire particle system. That way you could run two particle systems at the same location, one flipped and the other unflipped.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think flip the entire particle system won't make it looks like a wedding scene. Maybe I should just use a animation.
BTW, I've read your book, it's great, thank you Steffen!